# How to get random records from Strapi content API

Tags: strapi

I have records in strapi. I am using strapi content API. In my front-end, I need to display only 2 records randomly. For limiting, I have used limit query from content API. But random fetching what keyword I need to use. The official documentation doesn't provide any details regarding this - https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/content-api/parameters.html#available-operators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no official Strapi API parameter for random. You have to implement your own. Below is what I've done previously, using Strapi v3:

**1 - Make a service function**

File: `api/mymodel/services/mymodel.js`

This will contain our actual random query (SQL), and wrapping it in a service is handy because it can be used in many places (cron jobs, inside other models, etc).

```
module.exports = {
    serviceGetRandom() {

        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            
            // There's a few ways to query data.
            // This example uses Knex.
            const knex = strapi.connections.default
            let query = knex('mydatatable')

            // Add more .select()'s if you want other fields
            query.select('id')

            // These rules enable us to get one random post
            query.orderByRaw('RAND()')
            query.limit(1)

            // Initiate the query and do stuff
            query
            .then(record => {
                console.log("getRandom() record: %O", record[0])
                resolve(record[0])
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

**2 - Use the service somewhere, like a controller:**

File: `api/mymodel/controllers/mymodel.js`

```
module.exports = {

    //(untested)

    getRandom: async (ctx) => {

        await strapi.services.mymodel.serviceGetRandom()
        .then(output => {
            console.log("getRandom output is %O", output.id)
            ctx.send({
                randomPost: output
            }, 200)
        })
        .catch( () => {
            ctx.send({
                message: 'Oops! Some error message'
            }, 204) // Place a proper error code here
        })

    }

}
```

**3 - Create a route that points to this controller**

File: `api/mymodel/config/routes.json`

```
...
    {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/mymodelrandom",
        "handler": "mymodel.getRandom",
        "config": {
            "policies": []
        }
    },
...
```

**4 - In your front-end, access the route**

(However you access your API)

e.g. ajax call to `/api/mymodelrandom`

Answer (score 4):

This seem to work for me with Strapi v.4 REST API

Controller, Get 6 random entries

```
"use strict";

/**
 *  artwork controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::artwork.artwork", ({ strapi }) => {
  const numberOfEntries = 6;
  return {
    async random(ctx) {
      const entries = await strapi.entityService.findMany(
        "api::artwork.artwork",
        {
          populate: ["image", "pageHeading", "seo", "socialMedia", "artist"],
        }
      );

      const randomEntries = [...entries].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
      ctx.body = randomEntries.slice(0, numberOfEntries);
    },
  };
});
```

Route
random.js

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  routes: [
    {
      method: "GET",
      path: "/artwork/random",
      handler: "artwork.random",
      config: {
        auth: false,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

API

```
http://localhost:1337/api/artwork/random
```

[image]
[image]

To match default data structure of Strapi

```
"use strict";

/**
 *  artwork controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::artwork.artwork", ({ strapi }) => {
  const numberOfEntries = 6;
  return {
    async random(ctx) {
      const entries = await strapi.entityService.findMany(
        "api::artwork.artwork",
        {
          populate: ["image", "pageHeading", "seo", "socialMedia", "artist"],
        }
      );

      const randomEntries = [...entries]
        .sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
        .slice(0, numberOfEntries);

      const structureRandomEntries = {
        data: randomEntries.map((entry) => {
          return {
            id: entry.id,
            attributes: entry,
          };
        }),
      };

      ctx.body = structureRandomEntries;
    },
  };
});
```

[image]

There is also a random sort plugin.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-random-sort

Comment: Amazing, the plugin worked wonders, but why did I have to go through 30 mins of trial and error of your solution when I could have just installed the plugin and get it to work in 30 seconds . Please, move the plugin link to the very top of your solution!

Answer (score 3):

There is no API parameter for getting a random result.

So: FrontEnd is the recommended solution for your question.

You need to create a random request range and then get some random item from this range.

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
const firstID = getRandomInt(restaurants.length);
const secondID = getRandomInt(3);
const query = qs.stringify({
  id_in:[firstID,secondID ] 
});
// request query should be something like GET /restaurants?id_in=3&id_in=6
```

Comment: Thankyou. But I wasn't knew any info about the data. Like Id. Also IDs are not incremental integers here like the example.

Comment: How about getting all the items (if thats a responsible thing to do), then randomly choose from the list?

Comment: instead of getting all results which will take network time you can extend request range

Comment: Thank you @CemKaan, But I am using runtime fetch, which will gives obvious network delay.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this reliably is by two steps:

1. Get the total number of records
2. Fetch the number of records using `_start` and `_limit` parameters

```js
// Untested code but you get the idea

// Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

const { data: totalNumberPosts } = await axios.get('/posts/count');

// Fetch 20 posts
const _limit = 20;

// We need to be sure that we are not fetching less than 20 posts
// e.g. we only have 40 posts. We generate a random number that is 30.
// then we would start on 30 and would only fetch 10 posts (because we only have 40)
const _start = getRandomArbitrary(0, totalNumberPosts - _limit);

const { data: randomPosts } = await axios.get('/posts', { params: { _limit, _start } })
```

The problem with this approach is that it requires two network requests but for my needs, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seem to work for me with Strapi v4.3.8 and graphql

src/index.js

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {

  register({ strapi }) {
    const extensionService = strapi.service("plugin::graphql.extension");

    const extension = ({ strapi }) => ({
      typeDefs: `
        type Query {
          randomTestimonial: Testimonial
        }
      `,
      resolvers: {
        Query: {
          randomTestimonial: async (parent, args) => {
            const entries = await strapi.entityService.findMany(
              "api::testimonial.testimonial"
            );
            const sanitizedRandomEntry =
              entries[Math.floor(Math.random() * entries.length)];

            return sanitizedRandomEntry;
          },
        },
      },
      resolversConfig: {
        "Query.randomTestimonial": {
          auth: false,
        },
      },
    });

    extensionService.use(extension);
  },
  bootstrap({ strapi }) {},
};
```

graphql query:

```
  query GetRandomTestimonial {
    randomTestimonial {
      __typename
      name
      position
      location
      description
    }
  }
```

generate random testimonial on route change/refresh
https://jungspooner.com/biography